# Mac eclipse xdebug firefox issue

Tags: eclipse, macos, firefox, xdebug

I have worked with eclipse, firefox, and xdebug for months now on a linux-ubuntu machine. recently i moved to a mac 10.6 and set up all these programs and they all work fine until I try to run xdebug using firefox as the default browser in eclipse.

It will work, but the browser must be close other wise it will prompt a message saying

**Close Firefox:
A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time.**

and when this happens I can not debug, I have to close the browser and start the debugger again. This becomes very annoying after a few tries.

If I use safari I do not have this issue, it just opens a new tab and I can debug with no problems. I can live with this set up, but I prefer to use FF. any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure firefox is set as your default browser on your mac and then in eclipse go to preferences->general->web browser and select use external browser and in the window below select default system browser.

This should launch stuff as a new tab in firefox.